# Sencha Touch : .x-unsized vs .x-sized classes

Tags: extjs

In Sencha Touch How and on what basis .x-unsized or .x-sized classes get applied on sencha generated components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked this up in the sencha-touch.js & Component.js..

To look it up on detail, check "doRefreshSizeState()" in Component.js:

```
doRefreshSizeState: function() {
    var hasWidth = this.getWidth() !== null || this.widthLayoutSized || (this.getLeft() !== null && this.getRight() !== null),
        hasHeight = this.getHeight() !== null || this.heightLayoutSized || (this.getTop() !== null && this.getBottom() !== null),
        stretched = this.layoutStretched || this.hasCSSMinHeight || (!hasHeight && this.getMinHeight() !== null),
        state = hasWidth && hasHeight,
        flags = (hasWidth && this.LAYOUT_WIDTH) | (hasHeight && this.LAYOUT_HEIGHT) | (stretched && this.LAYOUT_STRETCHED);

    if (!state && stretched) {
        state = null;
    }

    this.setSizeState(state);
    this.setSizeFlags(flags);
}
```

To get rid of the "x-unsized" class, I set "width" + "height" on the button.

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Logout',
    id: 'logout',
    docked: 'right',
    width: 100,
    height: 10
}
```